# Possible to filter Spark dataframe by ISNUMERIC function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `DataFrame` for a table in SQL. I want to filter this `DataFrame` if a value of a certain column is numeric or not.

```
val df = sqlContext.sql("select * from myTable");
val filter = df.filter("ISNUMERIC('col_a')");
```

I want filter to be a dataframe of `df` where the values in `col_a` are numeric.

My current solution doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `filter` out as

```
df.filter(row => row.getAs[String]("col_a").matches("""\d+"""))
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the field in question to `DECIMAL` and inspect the result:

```
filter("CAST(col_a AS DECIMAL) IS NOT NULL")
```

Optionally, you can pass length and/or precision to narrow down the valid numbers to a specific maximum length:

```
filter("CAST(col_a AS DECIMAL(18,8)) IS NOT NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

[Shankar Koirala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51482947/2738164) covers integers effectively.  The regex below would cover use cases requiring doubles, with optional negative signing and handling of nulls (note that this is a Java variation):

```
df.filter( df.col("col_a").isNotNull() )
  .filter( ( FilterFunction<Row> )
      row -> row.getString( row.fieldIndex( "col_a" ) ).matches( "-?\\d+\\.?\\d*" ) )
```

Comment: @downvoter, any particular reason?  From my tests this works well and isn't a repeat of other answers.  If there's a logical issue, I'd love to know - I'm running this in production code and like to fix sneaky bugs.

Answer (score -1):

```
spark.sql("select phone_number, (CASE WHEN LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number),'[^0-9]', '')) = LENGTH(TRIM(phone_number)) THEN true ELSE false END) as phone_number_isNumeric from table").show()
```

This is really an old post, but still if anybody looking for alternate solution.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(phone_number),'[^0-9]', ''
```

removes all characters except numeric