# Need the equivalent of SQL IsNumeric function in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Like we have SQL ISNUMERIC Function which validates whether the expression is numeric or not , I need if there is any equivalent function in Spark SQL, I have tried to find it but couldn't get it. Please if someone can help or suggest for the same ?

Comment: So, do you need to filter the Rows after made the SQL execution??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to filter Spark dataframe by ISNUMERIC function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51482760/possible-to-filter-spark-dataframe-by-isnumeric-function)

Comment: Yes but, that solution is in scale. I guess he is wondering in Java. Well, he should specific which language.

Comment: I need to use isnumeric function in Azure databricks where I am using spark sql

Answer (score 3):

Try using spark udf, this approach will help you clone any function -

```
scala> spark.udf.register("IsNumeric", (inpColumn: Int) => BigInt(inpColumn).isInstanceOf[BigInt])
res46: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,BooleanType,Some(List(IntegerType)))

scala> spark.sql(s""" select "ABC", IsNumeric(123) as IsNumeric_1  """).show(false)
+---+-----------+
|ABC|IsNumeric_1|
+---+-----------+
|ABC|true       |
+---+-----------+


scala> spark.sql(s""" select "ABC", IsNumeric("ABC") as IsNumeric_1  """).show(false)
+---+-----------+
|ABC|IsNumeric_1|
+---+-----------+
|ABC|null       |
+---+-----------+
```

Here, above function will return null if column value is not integer.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: In where clause as well?

Comment: Yes you can use spark udf in where clause.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming here by way of Google :) , there is an alternative answer by regex for isnumeric in spark sql

```
select 
OldColumn, 
CASE WHEN OldColumn not rlike '[^0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS OldColumnIsNumeric
from table
```

The regex simply checks if the column is numeric or not.

You can modify to fit for substrings of the column you are checking too.